# dynamic memory allocation for string

Tags: c++

I am a c++ beginner. I am trying to allocate memory dynamically. Following is a part of my code

```
string[] Line = new string[3];

Line[0] = (0x01 == (0x01 & Config)) ? "x" : "y";
Line[1] = (0x02 == (0x02 & Config)) ? "a" : "b";
```

error is : undeclared identifier "Line".
Where I am going wrong?

Comment: First, C++ is not Java.  Second, why allocate anything when you can just declare an array of 3 strings?

Comment: What about using `std::vector<std::string> Line(3,"")`?

Comment: You don't need to use `new`: try not using `new` for your first 100 hours of C++ programming.

Comment: How many strings do you really want?

Comment: You're going to have to learn the language! Which book are you using?

Comment: The reason you're getting that error is that the declaration of `Line` has errors, causing `Line` not to be declared. You should handle compilation errors in the order they occur.

Answer (score 2):

```
string[] Line = new string[3];
```

This is much more like Java than C++ (it's not valid C++ at all). If you want an array of 3 `string`s, just do the following:

```
string Line[3];
```

Answer (score 1):

Static array of strings of size 3:

```
std::array<std::string, 3> line;
```

Dynamic array of strings:

```
std::vector<std::string>   line;
```

But judging by your array name, you probably just want a single string. That is all that is needed to hold a line.

Comment: Some people hold a convention of naming arrays in the singular, so that e.g. "Line 1", "Line 2" can be read. Some people, not me.

Answer (score 0):

Allocate as:

```
string *Line = new string[3]; // dynamic allocation
```

When not in use, deallocate as:

```
delete [] Line;
```

Otherwise, use statically allocated array as:

```
string Line[3];
```

after either of these, your statements are valid:

```
Line[0] = (0x01 == (0x01 & Config)) ? "x" : "y";
Line[1] = (0x02 == (0x02 & Config)) ? "a" : "b";
```

Comment: anything wrong in this? Why I have been down voted, don't understand

Comment: Because using `new[]` and `delete[]` is very outmoded, for good reason, and teaching it to obvious language newcomers is irresponsible. That being said, your answer is technically correct, and you did not get a downvote from me.

Answer (score 0):

Use *vector* as it allows you to redimension arrays and contains iterators

```
vector<string> vString(3);//vString is an array that contains 3 elements
```

You can then allocate as in a normal array

```
vString[0]=.....;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your question is just about setting characters in a single string, you can do this:

```
std::string Line;
Line.push_back((0x01 == (0x01 & Config)) ? 'x' : 'y');
Line.push_back((0x02 == (0x02 & Config)) ? 'a' : 'b');
```